# replacing text in a chemical formula string

Tags: regex, chemistry

I'm having trouble writing a function that will take a chemical formula string such as "NiNFe(AsO2)2" and remove one of the elements.
my current attempt is:

```
pattern = new RegExp(symbol, "g")
formula.replace(pattern, "")
```

If the symbol is "N" and the formula is "NiNFe(AsO2)2" I end up with "iFe(AsO2)2" instead of the desired "NiFe(AsO2)2". Does anyone know how to code this in such a way that it would distinguish the N from the Ni and replace just that?

Comment: Use a negative lookahead to check that you don't have a lowercase letter after: `(?![a-z])`. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RegExp(symbol+'(?![a-z])','g');` will match the symbol if it is not followed by a lower case letter

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative lookahead. The following will also remove any quantifier it may have:

```
pattern = new RegExp(symbol + "(?![a-z])" + "\d*", "g");
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you want to avoid using negative lookahead (eg. javascript supports it but some other regex engines don't), you could simply match `symbol + "([^a-z])"` and replace with `$1`.